# opening an application from different windows

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Hi i have if statement where i check local data and depending on this open my window. (or page i still haven't figured it out how it named) I **need open my first window in dependence

on the field isAutoLogin**. How i can make it help me pls and i wouldn't mind a better practice.
App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
    
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new AppShell();
            var isAutoLogin = Preferences.Default.Get("AutoLogin", false);
            if (isAutoLogin) Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
            else Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPageViewModel"); // i'm to lazy to change name
    
        }
    }
```

And my shell:
May i binding 2 pages right here?

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp3.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp3.MVVM.View"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPageViewModel}"
        Route="MainWindowViewModel" />

</Shell>
```

"

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly UsersViewModel _usersViewModel;

    public MainPage(UsersViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        _usersViewModel = viewModel;
    }

public partial class LoginPageViewModel : ContentPage
{
    private readonly UsersViewModel _usersViewModel;
    public LoginPageViewModel(UsersViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        _usersViewModel = viewModel;
    }
}
```

every time i start with LoginPage but need start to MainPage

Comment: Okey, im finally finde out what i need to do. First link helped me with understood how works navigation stack https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage. Netx link it is what i need add to my code for my navigation stack works correct  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#relative-routes